# TestNG DataProvider reading test data from the testng.xml config file?

Tags: testing, testng

Is it possible for a TestNG DataProvider to read test data from the testng.xml config file?  Or is this unrealistic for some reason?   I would like to be able to read test data from that file at the suite level and class level.

So, given a testing.xml file like this (which I am unsure is realistic or not), how would I do this?  I have written a DataProvider using XStream (or Jackson) before and so I am well versed in my own custom .xml format, but sticking to the strict format of the testing.xml is where I am worried about this.

**The following testing.xml is obvious invalid but I am just trying to show the kind of thing I would like to do:**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > 
<suite name="TestAll"> 
  <parameter name="hubUrl" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"/>
  <parameter name="reportFile" value="CustomReport.html"/>
  <test name="etsy">
    <parameter name="reportFile" value="CustomReport.html"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="qa.examples.suite.TestSearch">
        <parameter name="appUrl"  value="http://etsy.com" type="java.lang.String"/> 
        <parameter name="browser"  value="Firefox" type="java.lang.String"/>    
        <parameter name="testEnabled" value="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"/> 
        <methods>                 
          <include name="testEtsySearch"/>
            <tests>
              <test>
                <parameter name="testNum" value="1" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
                <parameter name="searchTerm" value="cell phone" type="java.lang.String"/>
                <parameter name="searchTerm" value="batteries" type="java.lang.String"/>
              </test>
              <test>
                <parameter name="testNum" value="2" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
                <parameter name="searchTerm" value="buttons" type="java.lang.String"/>
                <parameter name="searchTerm" value="metal" type="java.lang.String"/>
              </test>
            </tests>
          </include>                       
        </methods> 
      </class>
      <class name="qa.examples.suite.TestFilters" />
    </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

So, is something like this possible?  If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to pass ITestContext as a data provider parameter.
Something like:

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataProvider")
public static Object[][] Provider(ITestContext context) throws Exception
{
    String dataFile = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("dataFile");
}
```

Suite xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > 
<suite name="suite"> 
  <parameter name="param1" value="val1"/>
  <test name="test">
    <parameter name="param2" value="val2"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="test.TestClass1" />
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

test class

```
package test;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass1 {

@DataProvider(name="Provider")
public Object[][] provider(ITestContext context)
{
 Map<String, String> testParams = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameters();
 Map<String, String> suiteParams=context.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getParameters();

 return new Object[][]{{suiteParams.get("param1"), testParams.get("param2")}};
}

@Test(dataProvider="Provider")
public void test1(String param1, String param2)
{
 System.out.println("Param1: " + param1);
 System.out.println("Param2: " + param2);
}
```

}

Output

```
[TestNG] Running:
/home/nightmare/workspace/test/suite.xml

Param1: val1
Param2: val2

===============================================
suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Are you sure that works?  In my experience the data provider method is ran before the suite (because of Retention set to runtime) and so how can it possibly know the context of individual tests?  Those contexts are not known until the tests are running: am I wrong?

Comment: Once I realized that all of the Configuration methods in TestNG can take some sort of context argument, a whole world has opened up for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently passing only Suite Level Parameters from my XML. This is how I would do it - 
I would create a class - readParamsFromXML.

```
@Parameters( { "suiteParam1", "suiteParam2" } )
@BeforeSuite
public void getSuiteLevelParamsFromXML(
    @Optional("defaultValueForSuiteParam1")String SuiteParam1, 
    @Optional("defaultValueForSuiteParam2")String SuiteParam2 ) {
     <Some  Logic here based on the params passed>
}
```

I would extend a similar logic to read params at Test level & Method level by creating methods like - getTestLevelParamsFromXML & getMethodLevelParamsFromXML. I would add annotations like @BeforeClass & @BeforeMethod respectively for the above methods.

Now, all my test cases should extend readParamsFromXML class. This way - suite, test & class level parameters passed from XML could be available in test methods

Might not be the best way to get things done. But works perfectly for me.