# Does TestNG allow multiple data sets when using the testng.xml file?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, data-driven-tests

I have been able to do data-driven testing by hard-coding test values into a DataProvider:

```
@DataProvider(name = "XXXData")
public Object[][] createXXXData() {
    // Our test values here are hard-coded, which is OK
    // You could also, say, read an Excel file and create the parameter sets on the fly
    // The three values are: string to use, expected alphabetic, expected numeric count
    return new Object[][] {
            { "a1a", 2, 1},
            { "b2", 1, 2},  // Wrong num count - will fail
            { "cc333", 2, 3},
            { "d44dd44", 3, 4},
            { "eeee55555", 5, 5},   // Wrong alpha count - will fail
            { "ffff", 4, 0},
            { "000", 0, 3},
    };
```

I want to try to do the same thing using testng.xml. (Some of my colleagues have a prejudice towards have test data in separate file from code).

I am able to execute one data set, as below. However, none of the many examples I have seen on the 'net have multiple values, paralleling what I have shown above.

Does testng.xml does not support this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="ParameterExampleSuite" parallel="false">
    <test name="ParameterTest">
        <classes>
            <parameter name="message" value="a1a"></parameter>
            <parameter name="alphaCount" value="2"></parameter>
            <parameter name="numericCount" value="1"></parameter>
            <class name="com.Acme.Business.Safes.XXX.XXXTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I understand that I can write code in my createXXXData() to read an external file and create a data set based on that. 
This is all using IntelliJ.
This question similar to [TestNG DataProvider reading test data from the testng.xml config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290122/testng-dataprovider-reading-test-data-from-the-testng-xml-config-file). However, the answers there do not seem to match the use case. Certainly the answers are no more convenient than reading an Excel or xml file in the program itself.

Comment: Prejudice towards external file - why would that be?  If something is a correct approach, then it has to be stood for.  Today you have 5 datasets, this might quickly grow with new features introduction.  Your xml will get messy.

Comment: @niharika_neo That's an excellent question, although not strictly germane to finding an answer. My software test group is not comfortable editing source code files, and would prefer to be able to modify test coverage by editing a text file. (This is a silly situation, but not quite as silly as it might sound. The test group's expertise is in the domain of the system usage). In the end, editing an XML file is probably not acceptable either, but I wanted to understand the options. (Also, I don't know as the XML will be much "messier" than the Java source file, but that's a quibble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define multiple tests instead of defining params in the classes tag.  (I still believe you should be having the data in external file then doing this in the xml)

```
<test name="Automation Test Results" >
    <parameter name="name" value="NV"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="framework.tests.TestParams">
            <methods><include name="test1"></include></methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Automation Test Results2" >
    <parameter name="name" value="NV1"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="framework.tests.TestParams">
            <methods><include name="test2"></include></methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Comment: Exactly answers my question. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static method on a different class and use that by **dataProviderClass** in your test. By that all of your data will be in a separate file.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that possibility in my question.